# Connect to host mongodb from docker container

Tags: node.js, mongodb, docker, networking, containers

So I want to connect to my mongodb running on my host machine (DO droplet, Ubuntu 16.04). It is running on the default `27017` port on localhost.

I then use [mup](https://github.com/zodern/meteor-up) to deploy my Meteor app on my DO droplet, which is using docker to run my Meteor app inside a container. So far so good.
A standard `mongodb://...` connection url is used to connect the app to the mongodb.
Now I have the following problem:

`mongodb://...@localhost:27017...` obviously does not work inside the docker container, as `localhost` is not the host's localhost.

I already read many stackoverflow posts on this, I already tried using:

- `--network="host"` - did not work as it said `0.0.0.0:80` is already in use or something like that (nginx proxy)
- `--add-host="local:<MY-DROPLET-INTERNET-IP>"` and connect via `mongodb://...@local:27017...`: also not working as I can access my mongodb only from localhost, not from the public IP

This has to be a common problem!

**tl;dr** - What is the proper way to expose the hosts `localhost` inside a docker container so I can connect to services running on the host? (including their ports, e.g. 27017).

I hope someone can help!

Answer (score 43, accepted):

You can use: `172.17.0.1` as it is the default host ip that the containers can see. But you need to configure Mongo to listen to `0.0.0.0`.

From docker 18.03 onwards [the recommendation](https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-mac/networking/#i-want-to-connect-from-a-container-to-a-service-on-the-host) is to connect to the special DNS name `host.docker.internal`

For previous versions you can use DNS names `docker.for.mac.localhost` or `docker.for.windows.localhost`.

Comment: You good sir are my hero of the day! Thanks a lot!! Couldn't find this very simple answer anywhere.

Comment: @Robert: is 172.17.0.1 the ip address of the mongo container or the Gateway IP for default bridge? I tried 172.17.0.1 and my deployment failed. My mongodb container IP is 172.17.0.2. If I give that IP, all works fine. 
However, these IP might change based on how/when a particular container is deployed.

Comment: `172.17.0.1` is the Gateway IP, which is the host running docker (it is not a container). And yes, that IP could be another if there is a custom docker network defined.

Comment: `docker.for.mac.localhost` is very useful for my case, `0.0.0.0` doesn't work.

Comment: https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-mac/networking/ (I WANT TO CONNECT FROM A CONTAINER TO A SERVICE ON THE HOST)

Seems now there is a built-in DNS `host.docker.internal` for containers to connect the host.

Comment: **docker.for.mac.localhost** worked perfect  for mac ... but when i deployed on ubuntu i dint find any equivalent option to that.

Comment: Just a note that binding to 0.0.0.0 can lead to security issues if done on a public facing server.

Answer (score 3):

change the bindIp from 127.0.0.1 to 0.0.0.0 in /etc/mongod.conf. Then it will work

Comment: Just a note that binding to 0.0.0.0 can lead to security issues if done on a public facing server.

Answer (score 0):

or start mongod on ubuntu with a flag to bind all ip address as a temporary workaround (dev/learning purposes)

```
$ mongod --bind_ip_all
```

Answer (score 0):

Tried 100500 variants for **Windows** (using docker desktop), but without any result...

Unfortunately, currently, Windows (at least docker desktop) is not supporting --net=host

Quoted from: https://docs.docker.com/network/network-tutorial-host/#prerequisites

> The host networking driver only works on Linux hosts, and is not supported on Docker for Mac, Docker for Windows, or Docker EE for Windows Server.

You can try to use https://docs.docker.com/toolbox/