# Unable to connect container app with mongodb on Digital Ocean

Tags: node.js, mongodb, bash, docker, digital-ocean

this is the issue.

I have a MERN app containerized and hosted on Digital Ocean droplet. Also, I installed a mongodb in the same droptlet (Outside the container). To connect my container app with mongo, I had to update the `/etc/mongodb.conf` and bind connection to 172.17.0.1 as recommended [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45461017/connect-to-host-mongodb-from-docker-container/45461181#45461181)

mongodb.conf:

```sh
...
bind_ip = 0.0.0.0
#port = 27017
...
```

docker run script app:

```sh
$ docker run -it -p 3001:3001 -e DB_HOST=mongodb://172.17.0.1:27017 --name container-app image:1.0-alpine
```

Here, everything is ok and working... however, after that, I created a user to secure my mongo connection with roles `readWrite` and `userAdminAnyDatabase` and now, is not working with the new connection `mongodb://user:pass@172.17.0.1:27017`

The most weird thing for me is that I connect to the db using mongoDBCompass, I run a migration, and also, if Ican connect with mongoshell (droplet).

```
$ mongo -u admin -p --authenticationDatabase admin
```

The error console print

```sh
Error connecting to the database
MongooseServerSelectionError: connect ECONNREFUSED 172.17.0.1:27017
    at NativeConnection.Connection.openUri (/usr/autopago/back/node_modules/mongoose/lib/connection.js:800:32)
    at Mongoose.connect (/usr/app/back/node_modules/mongoose/lib/index.js:339:15)
    at connect (/usr/app/back/libraries/mongodb.js:5:14)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/app/back/app.js:24:1)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1137:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1157:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:985:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:878:14)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1025:19)
    at Module.Hook._require.Module.require (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/pm2/node_modules/require-in-the-middle/index.js:80:39)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:72:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/app/back/index.js:2:13)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1137:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1157:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:985:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:878:14) {
  reason: TopologyDescription {
    type: 'Single',
    setName: null,
    maxSetVersion: null,
    maxElectionId: null,
    servers: Map { '172.17.0.1:27017' => [ServerDescription] },
    stale: false,
    compatible: true,
    compatibilityError: null,
    logicalSessionTimeoutMinutes: null,
    heartbeatFrequencyMS: 10000,
    localThresholdMS: 15,
    commonWireVersion: null
  }
}
```

Is something missing in the configuration ? I have read several blogs and I can not find the solution. I hope someone can help!

Comment: I assume database and the application both live within the same docker container (right?). Could you share how do you actually connect to the database from within the application (connection string configuration in particular - is it just `mongoose.connect("<connection_string>"`)?

Comment: nop. Like I said before, the app lives in the container, and that container lives in a droplet and mongo is istalled also on the droplet (without any container).  I mean, the droplet (Ubuntu Server) has a mongodb installed and app containerized.

Comment: I'm quite sure then that you can't access applications running on your host (mongo service) from within your docker container (your app). Just as your host can't access container's ports without the `-p` flag. In your case from containers perspective it does not see that port 27017 is occupied by mongo daemon.

Comment: Im not sure about this @MarekPiotrowski because previously, when mongo had no user, my app (inside docker container) connect with mongodb without credentials with no problems, any issue related to port, connection or ip. Now, I cant access from container when I put user and pass on mongo connection string. And user is correctly configured because I can access vía mongodb atlas or mongo shell.

Comment: Ah right, good point. Just noticed that you are using 172.17.0.1 from within your docker, which is your host's IP (at least for the container). Have you tried using mongoshell on the app's container to see if you can access the database with that particular user you have created? So, as you did: `mongo -u admin -p --authenticationDatabase admin`, but make sure you do it from the app's container and using the desired user, not the admin.